# Invoke async Func stored in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

I have a class that is responsible of storing a bunch of async Funcs to execute them later. The signature of each Func differs only on the Task type. Here is the class:

```
public class FuncStore<TParameters> {
  private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _funcCache = new();
  
  public void AddFunc<T>(string key, Func<TParameters, Task<T>> value) {
    _funcCache.Add(key, value);
  }
  
  public async Task ExecuteAllAsync(TParameters parameters) {       
    foreach(var (_, func) in _funcCache) {
      
      // Problem here. How do I invoke each lambda?          

    }
  }
}
```

Here is the parameters class for context:

```
public class DefaultParameters {
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And here is an example of use:

```
var store = new FuncStore<DefaultParameters>();
var lambda01 = (DefaultParameters parameters) => {
  var str = parameters.SomeProperty + "01"; // Whatever
  return Task<string>.FromResult(str); // Simulate async op
};
var lambda02 = (DefaultParameters parameters) => {
  var number = Convert.ToInt32(parameters.SomeProperty) + 2; // Whatever
  return Task<int>.FromResult(number); // Simulate async op
};

// These both lambdas differ on their return type
// one is Task<string> and the other is Task<int>
store.AddFunc("01", lambda01);
store.AddFunc("02", lambda02);

// Many other lambdas and additions later...
var parameters = new DefaultParameters();
await store.ExecuteAllAsync(parameters);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to invoke those lambdas. Here are my attempts so far:

```
  public async Task ExecuteAllAsync(TParameters parameters) {       
    foreach(var (_, func) in _funcCache) {
      
      // Problem here. How do I invoke each lambda?
      
      // Attempt 1:
      var typedFunc = func as Func<TParameters, Task<object>>; // NullReferenceExeption, the cast fails
      await typedFunc(parameters);
      
      // Attempt 2 (almost):
      var asDelegate = func as Delegate;
      // I manage to get the task...
      var task = (Task)asDelegate.DynamicInvoke(new object[]{ parameters });
      // ... but if I await it, I get a compile error: "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'"
      Console.WriteLine(await task);
    }
    
    await Task<int>.FromResult(0); // Just to make the compiler happy while I debug
  }
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qPQxyw) is the .NET Fiddle.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"These both lambdas differ on their return type"_ -no they don't because you've made them both string, which is probably a typo I guess.

Comment: Oooops, I didn't notice. Thanks @Jamiec

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it was asked already... A here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878720/invoke-async-func-stored-in-a-dictionary asked yesterday

Comment: Yes, it was me and I wrote it pretty quickly and the quality of the question suffered, so I decided to write a better version today. My apologies.

Comment: In fact your problem boils down to: "how to convert a `Task<WhateverType>` to `Task<object>`, which is a question about co-variance. As `Task` isn't covariant, you cannot convert the one to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `dynamic`, in both the function cache and the delegates:

```
var lambda01 = (DefaultParameters parameters) => {
    var str = parameters.SomeProperty + "01"; // Whatever
    return Task.FromResult<dynamic>(str); // Simulate async op
};
```

and:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, dynamic> _funcCache = new();

public void AddFunc(string key, Func<TParameters, Task<dynamic>> value) {
    _funcCache.Add(key, value);
}
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rTm8ZM

Answer (score -1):

Here is another implementation that does not use `dynamic`.

```
public class FuncStore<TParameters>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<TParameters, object>> _funcCache = new();

    public void AddFunc<T>(string key, Func<TParameters, Task<T>> value)
    {
        _funcCache.Add(key, value);
    }

    // Scenario 1: if you don't care about the results of tasks
    public async Task ExecuteAllAsync(TParameters parameters)
    {
        foreach (var (_, func) in _funcCache)
        {
            var function = (Task)func(parameters);
            await function;
        }
    }

    // Scenario 2: if you care about the results of Task<T>
    public async Task<string> ExecuteAllAsync2(TParameters parameters)
    {
        // string accumulator to store the results, but it can be a List<object> or whatever you need
        string accumulatedResult = string.Empty;

        foreach (var (_, func) in _funcCache)
        {
            var function = func(parameters);

            // individual checks for casting
            if (function is Task<object> stringTask)
            {
                accumulatedResult += await stringTask;
            }
            else if (function is Task<int> intTask)
            {
                accumulatedResult += (await intTask).ToString();
            }
            //(...)
        }

        return accumulatedResult;
    }
}
```